# A non well formed numeric value encountered with number_format()

Tags: php, casting, floating-point

I get server error on this code:

```
$value = "1223.65";
echo (number_format((float)$value, 2) + 0);
```

It seems that error occurs only with 4+ digit numbers.

Comment: Because `number_format` returns a formatted string, and since you haven't specified a separator (thousands are separated by `,` by default) on a number >= 1000 you're getting the string `1,223.65` returned. Then you try to do a math operation on that string `1,223.65` which is not a well formed numeric value, thus this notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number_format () function handles a numeric value, and returns that value formatted in string.

The error occurs with only more than four digits, because that is when you enter the **thousands separator**, "and the value "2" you entered means 2 digits of precision."

You can do as follows:

```
$value = (float)"1223.65";
echo ((float)number_format($value, 2) + 0);
```

See in PHP Documentation: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php